# git release/deployment process for single developer

Tags: git, version-control

I am a single developer working on a new site. my current setup consists of the following

- Local git repo
- remote git repo on beanstalkapp
- sourcetree on my mac to manage commits.

I commit often locally, when i reach the stage I have finished a task I push to the remote, one for backup and secondly i have beanstalk configured to deploy any commits to my webhost so I can check the code works there.

I have now reached the point where I want to put the first release live. this leaves me with a problem, in that i still need to test my code on the host before releasing it to live.

I must add the disclaimer that A) I am simple and B) git confuses the hell out of me past the way I currently use it.

What I want to do is ideally have 2 branch, one called Master and one called Test. That way when I commit to test and then push it to the remote Beanstalk will auto deploy it to my test server.

once I am happy with the code on the test server. I would like to promote that code(which could well consist of 10's of commits) to the Master branch and use beanstalk to do a manual deployment, so I can do it out of hours.

I know that I may well be missing the point of git and my thoughts on how to use it may well be way of how it should be used.

My question is, firstly is it at all possible to implement the above workflow and secondly how could I go about doing it.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by having `master` and `test` branches locally too. Commit away at `test`, push it when you feel it is up to be tested, fix any issues. Once everything is OK, do:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only test
```

(the last command ensures that `master` is only updated by adding new commits in `test`). Then you can push `master` for final depolyment. Go back to `test` and work away.

Comment: thanks for that, just to clarify do you mean the ff-only command will only take the new commits from test, from since the last time it was run?

Comment: @JaChNo, it will take changes from `test`, but *only* if they build on `master` (`master` just moves forward to `test`).